# amazon s3 renaming and overwriting files, recommendations and risks

Tags: amazon-s3, batch-rename

I have a bucket with two kinds of file names:

1. `[Bucket]/[file]`
2. `[Bucket]/[folder]/[file]`

For example, I could have:

1. `MyBucket/bar`
2. `MyBucket/foo/bar`

I want to rename all the `[Bucket]/[folder]/[file]` files to `[Bucket]/[file]` files (and thus overwriting / discarding the `[Bucket]/[file]` files).
So as in the previous example, i want `MyBucket/foo/bar` to become `MyBucket/bar` (and overwrite / duscard the original `MyBucket/bar`).

I tried two methods:

1. Using s3cmd's move command: `s3cmd mv s3://MyBucket/foo/bar s3://MyBucket/bar`
2. Using Amazon's SDK for php: `rename(s3://MyBucket/foo/bar, s3://MyBucket/bar)`

Both methods seem to work, but - considering I have to do this as a batch process on thousands of files,
**my questions are:**

1. Which method is preferred?
2. Are there other better methods?
3. **Must I delete the old files prior to the move/rename?** (it seems to work fine without it, but I might not be aware of risks involved)

Thank you.

Comment: Hello! I am also trying to move and overwrite folders (and their residing files) in a single bucket and I noticed you had: rename(s3://MyBucket/foo/bar, s3://MyBucket/bar). How does this work in PHP? Or does that line just work verbatim on an EC2?

Comment: @AndyBarlow, I have written a post about it in: http://eyalarubas.com/log/2012/10/16/using-aws-s3-stream-wrapper-for-php/. Contact me if you have more questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since I asked this question about 5 months ago, I had some time to gain some insights; so I will answer it myself:

From what I have seen, **there is no major difference performance-wise**.  I can imagine that calling `s3cmd` from within PHP might be costly, due to invoking an external process for each request; but then again - Amazon's SDK uses cURL to send it's requests, so there is not much of a difference.

One difference I did notice, is that **Amazon's SDK tends to throw cURL exceptions** (seemingly randomly, and rarely), but `s3cmd` did not crash at all. My scripts run on 10's of thousands of files, so I had to learn the hard way to deal with these cURL exceptions.
My theory is that cURL crashes when there is a communication conflict on the server (for example, when two processes try to use the same resource). I am working on a development server on which sometimes several processes access S3 with cURL simultaneously; these are the only situations in which cURL exhibited this behaviour.

**For conclusion:**
Using `s3cmd` might be more stable, but using the SDK allows more versatility and better integration with you PHP code; as long as you remember to handle the rare cases (I'd say 1 for every 1000 requests, when several processes run simultaneously) in which the SDK throws a cURL exception.

Answer (score 2):

Since either methods, s3cmd and SDK, will eveltually issue the same REST call, you can safely choose the one is best for you.

When you are moving a file, if the target exists, it is always replaced, then, if you don't want this behavior, you will need to check whether the target file name already exists, in order to perform or not the move operation.